# React input field unfocuses and causes re-renders on every letter input

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a React component that includes an input field, and I've noticed that whenever I enter even a single letter into the input field, it unfocuses, and the entire component appears to be re-rendered. This behavior is not desired, as it interrupts the user's input flow and may impact the overall performance of the application.
`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
export default function Dashboard() {
    const [course, setCourse] = useState("");
    const [Data, setData] = useState();
    const [SideBar, setSideBar] = useState("AvailableCourses")
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState([])
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation();
    const inputRef = useRef();
    const user = location.state.User;
    useEffect(() => {
       
        console.log("re rendered")
        const fetchData = async () => {
            // fetching some user data
            }
        
        const fetchCourses = async () => {
            // fetching data
        }
        fetchCourses()
        fetchData()
    }, [user]);
    const handleCourseChange = (event) => {
        setCourse(event.target.value);
    };

    const CourseForm = () =>{


        console.log("reredner")
        return( <div>
            <div className=" text-4xl font-sans font-semibold">
                Pubish a Course
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-1 min-h-screen justify-center items-center">
                <div className="container rounded-md border w-min border-slate-600 mt-6 p-4 shadow-md">
                    <div className="font-sans text-2xl font-semibold text-center">Login</div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter the Course Name"
                        value={course}
                        onChange={handleCourseChange}
                        className="block mt-2 p-2 border ml-6 mr-6 rounded-md"
                        ref={inputRef}
                    />
                    <div className="flex justify-center">
                        <button
                            onClick={() => {
                                console.log(course)
                            }}
                            className="block mt-4 px-4 py-2 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-md "
                        >
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
    const Info =  () => {
        if (user.teacher === true) {
            if (SideBar === "AvailableCourses") {
                if (courses.length > 0) {
                    return (
                        <div>
                            {courses.map((course) => { return (<div>a course</div>) })}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
                else {
                    return (
                        <div>No courses Available</div>
                    )
                }
            }
            else if (SideBar === "YourCourses") {
                if (Data.publishCourse.length > 0) {
                    return (<div>
                        {
                            Data.publishCourse.map((course) => { return <div> a course </div> })
                        }
                    </div>)
                }
                else {
                    return <div>You have not published any course yet!</div>
                }
            }
            else if (SideBar === "PublishCourse") {
                return (
                    <CourseForm/>
                )
            }
            else {
                if (Data.takeCourse.length > 0) {
                    return (<div>
                        {
                            Data.takeCourse.map((course) => { return <div> a course </div> })
                        }
                    </div>)
                }
                else {
                    return <div>You are not registered for any course yet!</div>
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (SideBar === "AvailableCourses") {
                if (courses.length > 0) {
                    return(
                        <div>
                    {courses.map((course) => { return (<div>a course</div>) })}
                    </div>
                    )
                }
                else {
                    return (
                        <div>No courses Available</div>
                    )
                }
            }
            else {
                if (Data.takeCourse.length > 0) {
                    return (<div>
                        {
                            Data.takeCourse.map((course) => { return <div> a course </div> })
                        }
                    </div>)
                }
                else {
                    return <div>You are not registered for any course yet!</div>
                }
            }
        }
    }
    const TeacherSidebar = () => {
        if (user.teacher === true) {
            return (<div className=" p-3">
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("AvailableCourses") }} >AvailableCourses</div>
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("YourCourses") }}>YourCourses</div>
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("RegisteredCourses") }}>RegisteredCourses</div>
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("PublishCourse") }}>PublishCourse</div>
            </div>)
        }
        else {
            return (null)
        }
    }
    const StudentSidebar = () => {
        if (user.teacher === false) {
            return (<div className=" p-3">
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("AvailableCourses") }}>AvailableCourses</div>
                <div className="text-base font-sans m-1" onClick={() => { setSideBar("RegisteredCourses") }}>RegisteredCourses</div>
            </div>)
        }
        else {
            return (null)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className=" justify-center p-1 text-lg font-medium font-sans flex bg-slate-100">
                <div className="">DashBoard</div>
            </div>
            <div className=" flex flex-row w-screen">
                <div className="flex border-r-2 w-min h-screen">
                    <TeacherSidebar />
                    <StudentSidebar />
                </div>
                <div className="  w-full ">
                    <div>
                        <div className=" ml-11 mt-4" >
                            <Info />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

`
Explanation of the code:

The component fetches data using useEffect hooks and sets some state variables.
There are several state variables (course, Data, SideBar, courses) and event handlers (handleCourseChange) used in the component.
The CourseForm component renders an input field, and it appears that interacting with this field is causing the problem.
Expected behavior:
I want the input field to retain focus even after entering letters, and I don't want the component to re-render on every letter input.

What I've tried so far:

I've checked for any unnecessary re-renders in the component, but I couldn't find any obvious causes.
I've examined the event handlers and useEffect hooks to see if they are triggering re-renders but couldn't pinpoint the issue, i am certain though that this isn't being caused by useEffect.
Would you please help me understand why the input field is losing focus and causing re-renders? And how can I fix this issue to have a smoother user experience?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can keep the input value state inside CaseFrom, this may stop input from losing focus.